# Import scene model into RVIZ/MoveIt

Tags: rviz, moveit, mesh, planning-environment, planning-scene

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am wanting to launch RVIZ and have it import laboratory environment into the planning scene.
I have a 3D model of the lab in SolidWorks and available as an STL.

How can I do this? Are there any parameters i can load this into?

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/164051/import-scene-model-into-rviz/moveit/) by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) on ROS Answers with karma: 327 on 2014-05-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@cmeaclem,

If, in Rviz, you navigate to the Motion Planning tab 'Scene Object' there is a window and button that lets you import a file. Once the file is loaded you can move your object in the world using the gui or imarkers and then save the config.

Hope this helps

**Update:** You can follow [this](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Environment_Representation/Rviz#Saving.2FImporting_From_a_Database) to save the scene to the warehouse database. Then you can load from the same tab after launching. The connect button does need to be clicked a few times in order to connect and you may need to change the [warehouse database path](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Benchmarking#Starting_the_MoveIt_Warehouse) to save. From then on, you should just need to load the scene from the Motion Planning > Stored Scene tab.

---

Originally posted by [JoSo](https://answers.ros.org/users/18857/joso/) with karma: 120 on 2014-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) on 2014-07-18**:
So if I save the RViz configuration it will automatically load that scene next time I run my rviz application?

**Comment by [JoSo](https://answers.ros.org/users/18857/joso/) on 2014-07-19**:
@cmeaclem Sorry, saving the Rviz configuration will save the display tabs that you have added to the left window pane. Handy, but not the answer I believe you need. See above for more accurate solution

**Comment by [SaltyFish](https://answers.ros.org/users/34821/saltyfish/) on 2018-04-25**:
I clicked the tab 'scene objects' and pressed the button 'import from text' ,but only *.scene file can be found, i can't choose my STL file.What should i do? thanks!

**Comment by [bao041115](https://answers.ros.org/users/53564/bao041115/) on 2020-06-02**:
Hello ! i have already imported file STL. However, the deviation is count on cm, i want it to use mm as the unit, can i fix this problem ? Thank you very much

**Comment by [Camsmart](https://answers.ros.org/users/108238/camsmart/) on 2022-07-05**:
@bao041115 I believe you can do this by scaling the object. I believe RVIZ uses meters by default, so scale this down/ up between the units.